# Google Chrome Developer tools shows browser default font size as 18 pixels?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

The default font size is known to be 16 pixels. I made a simple page and tested this out. I looked at the Developer Tools in Google Chrome and it says 18 (yes I removed margin and padding to the paragraph element). 
I ran the following JavaScript to manually get the font size to see if it was 16px and it was. **What is this number 18 from?**

```js
var el = document.getElementById('hello');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
console.log(fontSize);
```

```html
<p id='hello'>Hello world</p>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `line-height`. Set `line-height: 1;` and the height will be 16px.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('hello');
el.style.lineHeight = '1';
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
var fontSize = parseFloat(style);
console.log(fontSize);
```

```html
<p id='hello'>Hello world</p>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way using the developer tools to get the 16px without manually typing in the CSS (line-height in this case) or using JavaScript?

Comment: @MichaelColer what I meant was is there a way to get the default font size using the Developer Tools without having to manually enter in the `line-height`?

Comment: @RobertRocha if I'm understanding you correctly, no. Dev tools will always show the height/width of the element. To get it to show a different size, you have to resize the element - and in this case, that means removing `line-height` (or setting it to something different or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

The area selected by the Chrome Dev Tools includes the `line-height` (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/line-height), and any `padding` / `margin` around the `p` element.

- You can explore the padding and margin in the styles pane:

  [image]
- If there is no padding or margin (as in your example), then **this is simply the `line-height`**. Set it to `1` to get your expected output.